# Отображать чаcть URLа

Tags: javascript, location.hash

Доброго всем дня!

У меня возник вопрос. 
Имеется слайдер. Я хочу, чтобы при его вызове он добавлял в адресную строку адрес картинки. 
При добавлении

> location.hash = url

он добавляет полность адрес.

Получается:

> http://example.ru/news/id/1410#http://examle.ru/pictures/o/621/39.jpg

А я хочу, чтобы было что-то вроде:

> http://test2.tvc.ru/channel/brand/id/1410#46.jpg

**Обновление**

Точнее, чтобы адрес менялся на адрес картинки, а при закрытии возвращался исходный адрес.

Answer (score 1):

Так добавляйте просто id картинки:

```
window.location.hash = id; // будет site.ru/gallery/#39
```

Как раз на днях сделал похожее [упражнение](http://blackbook.archnadzor.ru/) (см. исходник).

Comment: Не работает это дело.
Может, есть метод, чтобы просто отображалась часть адреса? И нет особого желания использовать хэштег)

Comment: Без хэштега можно только в современных [браузерах с поддержкой](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history) HTML5 [History API](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/).